# What is reason of using ' [ ] ' notation to access javascript object members instead of dot notation?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

I am now reading some of open source javascript project codes and i see that sometimes they access object property like `person.name` but sometimes they access like `person['name']`.

For me dot notation is so much clear against other. Dot notation is easy to write and read but in source code i see that they are sometimes used dot notation sometimes [] braces notation and i am trying to understand what is the reason of it.

What can be reason of it ?

Answer (score 7):

First it can be dynamic with a string:

```
 var key = 'name';
 person[key];
```

Second, it also supports other symbols that aren't supported

```
 var key = 'first-name';
 person[key];
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a use case (having impossible property name)

```
var obj = {};
> undefined
obj['first name'] = 'Ivan';
> "Ivan"
obj['first name']
> "Ivan"
obj.first\ name
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
obj.first name
> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very good reason for using the brackets, where we're passing in the property name as a parameter:

```
function showProperty(propertyName) {
    alert(person[propertyName]);
}

showProperty('name');
showProperty('age');
```

Here is another good reason, where we can access the `'headers'` property of `request` using dot-notation, but we can *not* access the `'Content-Type'` property of `request.headers` using dot-notation, because it contains a `-`.

```
request.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html';
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very usefully to use this notation in methods, where you send your attribute name as parameter for example.

```
var Obj = function(){
    this.abc = function(){
        alert("abc!!!");
    };
    this.qqq = function(){
        alert("QQQ!!!");
    };
}

var showAlert = function(param){
    var myObj = new Obj();
    myObj[param]();
};

showAlert('abc');
```