# Accessing fields in .json file

Tags: javascript, json

I was following this article (https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-dashboard-widget) to create a widget to add it to microsoft dashboard.

In my html file, there is this piece of code that I cannot get to work:

```
...(some code above)
return TFS_Wit_WebApi.getClient().getRevision(284,6)
                        .then(function (query) {

                            var $list = query.rev;        
                            var $container = $('#query-info-container');
                            $container.empty();
                            $container.append($list);

... (some code below)
```

In this line:

```
  var $list = query.rev;
```

I'm trying to get access to .json file "rev" variable.

Here is my .json file

```
    {
      "count": 15,
      "value": 
      [
        {
          "id": 284,
          "rev": 1,
          "fields": {
            "System.WorkItemType": "User Story",
            "System.State": "New",
            "System.Reason": "New",
            "System.CreatedDate": "2016-06-23T14:31:37.567Z",
         }, 

...(some code below)
```

And I'm able to get access to this "rev" variable.

However, now I want to get access to "fields", namely to

```
"System.State": "New",
```

Instead of

```
var $list = query.rev;
```

I tried

```
var $list = query.fields.System.WorkItemType[0]; 
And 
var $list = query.value.fields[0];
and 
var $list = query.fields;
```

However, that did not work.

Here is some documentation on how it is supposed to be accessed

```
fields: {[key: string]: any}.
```

But it is not much of a help.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JSON objects as a kind of "map", what means they are composed of key-value pairs.

```
var $list = query.fields['System.State'];
```

---

There are many different ways of accessing a JSON object properties, as you have already mentioned in your question. However, if the property contains a dot or a space on its name, you need to fall back to the array notation. This means that the following attempts will yeld the correct result:

- `query.fields`
- `query[fields]`
- `query.fields['System.State']`
- `query[fields]['System.State']`

But the ones below will not:

- `query.fields.System.State`
- `query[fields].System.State`

This happens because, in the last two ways, JavaScript will think you are trying to access the `State` property of the `query.fields.System` object (which does not exist).

The same applies for objects that have a property whose name contain spaces. Accessing them as `object['my property']` will work, but using the dot notation with `object.my property` will not.

Additional questions regarding this can be seen here:

- [Dot Notation and Square Bracket Notation in JavaScript](http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/js-dot-notation/)
- [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)
- [What is reason of using ' [ ] ' notation to access javascript object members instead of dot notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267666/what-is-reason-of-using-notation-to-access-javascript-object-members-ins?lq=1)

Comment: I see, thank you! It worked! Also, have another quick question. Can I access the variables inside "fields" by the indices? Like, 

var $list = query.fields[0]; or something like that?

Comment: As the JSON object is a map, you will not be able to access it using indexes like 0, 1, 2 **unless** you explicitly define properties called 0, 1, 2... -- the index notation is used for traversing arrays, but not JSON  objects. You can iterate through all properties using [`for ... in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) (and be sure to check for the property using `hasOwnProperty` for safety).

Comment: Take a look here to see how you can do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object

Comment: Thank you! I'm still learning all these things and you helped me greatly!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 var $list = query.fields["System.WorkItemType"];
```

JavaScript will interpret the System and WorkItemType as nested properties because of the dot.

Answer (score 0):

Access to json elements is very easy:

1º Create a new var to transform the json data to a new object. Really json has the javascript object format.

```
var data = '{ "count": 15, "value": [ {"id": 284, "rev": 1, "fields": {"System.WorkItemType": "User Story", "System.State": "New", "System.Reason": "New", "System.CreatedDate": "2016-06-23T14:31:37.567Z", }, ...(some code below) '

var json = JSON.parse(data);
```

2º Access to a specific element of the object via “.” or “[]”:

Dot notation:

```
var json.value[n].fields['System.State'];
```

Note that you can use dot notation with System.State key.

[] notation:

```
var json['value'][n]['fields']['System.State'];
```

being `n` the index to access to a specific element of your object array